# game maker modifying windy woods game

Tags: game-engine, game-development, game-maker

I am a complete beginner in using game engines and creating games in general
I have a project to implement and I am trying to learn while implementing it at the same time
currently, I am using the Windy Woods template to build on it and have it execute the functionality that I want
I wanted to create a landing page and make it the first one when opening the game but I am getting an error and I am not sure where is it coming from:

> ############################################################################################ ERROR in action number 1 of Step Event1 for object
> obj_character_parent: Unable to find instance for object index 24 at
> gml_Script_check_collision (line 17) - var _left_top =
> tilemap_get_at_pixel(obj_game_manager.collision_tilemap, bbox_left +
> _move_x, bbox_top + _move_y); ############################################################################################ gml_Script_check_collision (line 17)
> gml_Object_obj_character_parent_Step_1 (line 6) - grounded =
> check_collision(0, 1);

[image]

Comment: I can see that the error happens when i add an object player to the instance layer but i still do not know how to resolve it

Comment: You're currently showing the Layers in the room, I think it'll help to know what kind of instances are present in the instance layer as well. I assume it's possible that it loads the player object before the obj_game_manager